# Transparent color texture in WebGL

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl, rgba

I am creating an RGBA texture out of an array of floats with the following code:

```
var dataTexture = new Uint8Array(array.length*4);
for(var i=0; i<dataTexture.length; i+=4)
{

    if(array[i/4]!=0)
    {
        dataTexture[i] = 255*parseFloat(array[i/4]);
        dataTexture[i+1] = 255*parseFloat(array[i/4]);
        dataTexture[i+2] = 255*parseFloat(array[i/4]);
        dataTexture[i+3] = 255;
    }
}

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.mTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataTexture);      
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

and it shows up as a black and white image. How can I put a transparent color map on top to make it appear not black and white, but in color? I tried the following code before the above code, but to no avail:

```
var x = new Uint8Array([55, 155, 255, 120]);
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, x);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Thank you!

Comment: this `255*255*0.5, 255*255*255*0.5` will wrap around, as uint8 only has a range of [0-255], why not create a `LUMINANCE` float texture using [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/) ?

Comment: @LJᛃ, unfortunately, my GPU doesn't support OES_texture_float.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? OES_texture_float is supported on 96.7% of PCs...
Either way you're writing RGBA data, so ... just multiply your RGB values with some color?